# This dependency was not found:

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, less, lesshat

**My error:**

```
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-2ec75e7e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!less-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Footer.vue in ./src/components/main/Footer.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-2ec75e7e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!less-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./F
```

***I working whith vue.js webpack ... plss give me some advice to get rid of this mistake...***

Answer (score 1):

Based on this error message, it is shown that the two dependencies do not exist, so installing them will solve the problem

You can try to run the following commands:

```
npm install -S vue-style-loader css-loader
```

Comment: Can you add some more details about your answer? It would help anyone goes to this question later

Comment: + css-loader@0.28.11
+ vue-style-loader@3.1.2
updated 2 packages in 13.793s

Comment: installed but still same issue    :(